# disable UIViewController content animating on iPhone rotation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiviewcontroller

I need to implement behavior of my UIViewController subclass like in standart iPod.app: when device rotated from portrait to landscape, content of UIViewController stay's still and new view add's above it.

The problem is that, when set

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

the content is rotating

but when set

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return NO;
}
```

function

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    NSLog(@"did rotate form interface orientation %d",fromInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

is newer called

So, do you know how to handle device rotation inside UIViewController without rotating it content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you do NOT want your viewController to respond to interface orientation rotation.

Instead, it is easier just to observe UIAccelerometer notifications. Then do a full swap of the view.

You can see the code to do this here on SO:

[Rotating the iPhone, and instantiating a new UIViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730799/rotating-the-iphone-and-instantiating-a-new-uiviewcontroller/893785#893785)

and

[UIDevice Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930075/uidevice-orientation/930336#930336)