# How can I get the real device's orientation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, orientation, uidevice

All,
   When i locked the screen orientation,i want use **[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]** to get screen's orientation ,but it always return **UIDeviceOrientationPortrait**, so, question is how can i get the real Device's orientation.
thank you very much.

Comment: Did you test this on simulator or device ? I believe this will give exact result on real device only.

Comment: Go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930075/uidevice-orientation

Comment: You can refer this [so called question][1] and get your problem resolved. [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634745/iphone-orientation Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're enabling orientation notifications via:

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];`

If that still doesn't work, you can also use the status bar to figure out the current orientation (if your UI is rotating) via:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];`

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing in the Simulator then be aware that the Simulator is terrible at returning accurate orientation values. Test on a device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on orientation notification generation first, as per [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW15).

You need to call:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

*Then* you can  check the device's orientation. You need to tell the device that you are done getting the orientation, to conserve battery. You do so by calling:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Personally, I've had better luck with [using the status bar's orientation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This is because sometimes, (when the device is flat on a surface, for example) the device orientation won't be "Landscape" or "Portrait".

Comment: [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] does not work if the user has locked his device orientation from the Springboard. orientation is always the last value, and there are no notifications for changes.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be detect orientation from CoreMotion library. It would fix a bug when Portrait Orientation Lock: On.
Refer that article: http://codrspace.com/yuvirajsinh/device-orientation-detection-using-coremotion/