# UIDEVICE orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface, device-orientation

hello all i have my splash screen which i want to show in landscape mode and all other screen in potrait mode. My root view controller is acting as a splash screen i am writing this code in viewdidload method

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

But this code is not working and shows me that UIdevice may not respond to setorentation please guide me that how could i change the orentation for only first splash screen  and also other screen should be in potrait mode

Comment: See also [iPhone orientation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/634745/194544)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`UIDeviceOrientation` refers to the physical orientation of the device whereas `UIInterfaceOrientation` refers to the orientation of the user interface. You can't change the physical orientation of the device, but you can change how the status bar is displayed via `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation`

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just have a splash screen that is displayed sideways?

The user will interpret that as a "landscape" splash and adjust accordingly, whether or not your application actually thinks it is. Just make sure to return `NO` in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` so it doesn't rotate away when the user turns it.

But a **warning**: it's probably worthwhile to tweak your splash screen so it is in the portrait orientation, since it may be annoying to suggest to the user that your app likes landscape, and then switch to portrait as soon as it actually starts.

If you really want to, though, you can use [setStatusBarOrientation:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setStatusBarOrientation:animated:) on the `UIApplication` to force the orientation.

Comment: yes i can do that but i just need to confirm that if there is any other standard way to set device orientation  for a particular screen which would not effect the other screen? if it is there that would be great 

thank you very much for your answer

Comment: ok thank you very much for your valuable advice i will follow this guidline