# How to check the orientation of device programmatically in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634745/iphone-orientation)

How to check the orientation of device at any point off time programmatically in iPhone ?

Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicated [iPhone orientation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/634745/194544)

Comment: Try this : http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/07/check-device-orientation.html

Comment: You could use a method like the willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator: This method is called any time the trait collection of the view controller changes. Traits can be the horizontal and vertical size classes. So inside the method we can check the following (in Swift):switch newCollection.verticalSizeClass { case .Compact:
//it's landscape case .Regular, .Unspecified:
//It's portrait }

Answer (score 75):

Here are macros `UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape` and `UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait`

so rather checking separately you can do it like this ...

```
   if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
         // code for landscape orientation      
    }
```

OR

```
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
         // code for Portrait orientation       
    }
```

Comment: this method works great, but for me only work inside of viewDidAppear method. Im using stroyboad. It is correct ?

Comment: This does not work again in iOS8

Answer (score 17):

Try it.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

if ( ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] ==  UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)  )
{
   // do something for Portrait mode
}
else if(([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) || ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft))
{
   // do something for Landscape mode
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Try also:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)
```

and

```
UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)
```

Answer (score 7):

`-[UIViewController interfaceOrientation]`

However it is possible to retrieve the deviceOrientation, independent from the current interface orientation:

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]`

Read the documentation for more information though, you need to do some more things to make that work.

Answer (score 4):

You can also check within the function

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations

    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
       //do for portrait
    }       
    else 
    { 
       //do for Landscape 
    }
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || 
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should place `[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];` in your `AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Then, anywhere in your application you can get the current orientation with:

`UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];`

And test orientation with:

`UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)`
`UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)`

Comment: You should test the variable `orientation` using `UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape` not using `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape`.