# iphone curl transition in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, curl, landscape

the question is known: how to make curl transition in application with landscape mode only? by default it does not make it from bottom to top, but from left to right

Known solution is to add extra view and add animated views to it, but

I have to show regular view, then curl it up and show tabbarcontroller, so tabbar controller must be under super view... the question is how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the orientation of the device before choosing the transition.

See:

[How to check the orientation of device programmatically in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600097/how-to-check-the-orientation-of-device-programmatically-in-iphone)