# How to change device orientation when app returns to foreground in iOS

Tags: ios8, screen-orientation

I am making an app which supports only portrait orientation in some pages, while in others, it supports only landscape mode. The problem I am facing is when I'm in landscape mode in one of the pages (I don't allow orientation change on screen rotation), and I press the home button to take the app into background mode,then when I come back into the app, it opens in portrait mode. How can I check and change device orientation in appWillEnterForeground method/ when app returns to foreground?

Answer (score 2):

(already answered here: [How to check the orientation of device programmatically in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600097/how-to-check-the-orientation-of-device-programmatically-in-iphone) )

However, check out property orientation of UIDevice ( [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation ), for example:

**Landscape:**

> ```
> if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
> {
>      // code for landscape orientation      
> }
> ```

**Portrait:**

> ```
> if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
> {
>      // code for Portrait orientation       
> }
> ```

Comment: yes, but I have to forcefully change the device orientation to landscape mode when I return back to the app from background, as now if I press the home button while the app runs in landscape mode, then when I come back, it opens in portrait mode.