# Segment Bar in iOS accross different Size classes

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uisegmentedcontrol, size-classes

I'm using `UISegmentController` (default provided by iOS). I want to show text for iPad or iPhone landscape view. Where as in case of iPhone, I want to show icons (not text) in the same segment bar. 
Is it possible? If yes, then **how can I achieve this in story board or programmatically?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding `UISegmentedControl` programatically.
Code is as follows in controller `viewWillAppear` method,

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
UISegmentedControl * cntrl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]  initWithItems:@[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Circle"],@"2"]];
cntrl.frame = CGRectMake(30, 100, 200, 50);
[self.view addSubview:cntrl];
}
```

With above code we're creating segment control with one image in first segment and text in second segment. Check attached screenshot.

Use following code to check either device is iPad or iPhone

```
-(BOOL) isiPad {
return UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;
}
```

Based on the type of the device, customise segment control.

For existing segment control, when you want to set image,

```
[cntrl setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tick"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

use above method by specifying which image you want to set at particular segmentIndex.

At the same way when you want to set text at particular index, use

```
    [cntrl setTitle:@"Hello" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thanks, but i already have a segment control in story board and it's outletReferance in my view controller. i just want to update icons on basis of device (for the same control @Bharath Vankireddy

Comment: Check my updated answer. That should solve your problem.

Comment: yes, i did it this way and was about to post the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Wc, if this solved your problem, you can accept this answer too.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt seem possible to use the storyboard completely on its own to do this kind of functionality, but a combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7696332/1219956) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167255/1219956) inside your viewDidLoad might get you want you want

Comment: if you dont have an option like this in the picture then you arent using size classes for your storyboard (which can be turned on in the file inspector, first tab on the top right toolbar)

Comment: thanks, but i'm using size classes and getting the option as in above picture. the problem is, when i set image for one size class (say wAny hCompact), i appears for all. same is the case with text @Fonix

Comment: so do you have it like, any/any = icons, then any/compact = text and regular/regular = text ?

Comment: i guess maybe the storyboard isnt clever enough to have different values for the different size classes then, might have to do it programmatically then unfortunately

Comment: i have any/any = text, then compact/any=icons and then any/compact=icon.. i set in the sequence mentioned. but when i run, it's always the last thing (icons in my case) for all the size classes

Comment: yes, i think the same. but now i don't know how to do that programatically :/

Comment: i think you need to use a combination of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7696332/1219956) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10167255/1219956)