# About the orientation of iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How to get the current orientation of iPhone?
I surfed this site, and found two methods as followings.

- [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
- [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

Which one is the right way to get the current orientation ?
I tried two methods under simulator 4.1, but there are some problems for both methods.

Comment: See also [iPhone orientation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/634745/194544) thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` gets the current physical orientation of the device. `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation` gets the orientation of the UI. If the app ever returns NO to the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method, the two values will not be the same.

Comment: Thank you for showing me a clear picture about those two methods.

Comment: Something to note: If you have the device on a flat surface, `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` may not return the value you want. I had an interface I dynamically layout based on user input that went wonky on me when I used that.  Using the `statusBarOrientation` seems to be working great.

Answer (score 6):

Register your class to listen to UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification then handle the device orientation accordingly.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
addObserver:self
selector:@selector(deviceRotated:)
name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
```

and handle the device's orientation properly:

```
- (void)deviceRotated: (id) sender{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp ||
        orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown)
    {
        //Device rotated up/down
    }

    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
    }
    else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
    }
    else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I vote up because one answer for one question. The way works well, and thank you.