# UIViewController - orientation changes don't get reported

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, uidevice

In my UIViewController subclasses, I impliment `- (void)didAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation`, but it never gets called, although I have correctly implemented `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` and my views do get rotated.

Comment: @JoePasq: Nope. It somehow solved itself, though...

Comment: I have this problem also. I'm trying to change a subview managed by another view controller midway through rotation. Similar to iAds switching frame sizes in rotation.

Comment: @JoePasq: Well, make sure you do what whitman proposed in his answer. I don't know whether it solves the problem, but you should try it.

Comment: I'm using device notifications to solve it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273895/how-to-autorotate-a-subview-in-navigation-controller
What he proposed is what the docs say, it should be right, I'm not sure what the underlying issue it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also implement willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation for the did... to get called. I suspect the framework first tries to call the will... and if it doesn't find it implemented it assumes you didn't implement the did... either, and so never calls it.