# Need Help Checking What Orientation iPad is in

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634745/iphone-orientation)

Depending on what orientation the iPad is in, I need to either set the table view's background or remove it because it doesn't work with the popover.

I tried this but no luck:

```
if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ){
    self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]; 
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    NSLog(@"test");
```

Maybe there is a better way? To see if table is master or popover, then set background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you want, more or less:

1. `UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];`
2. A more hack-ish method would be to check the width of the status bar.

If you go with option 1, then you can check the orientation like so:

```
switch (orientation) {
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        // Do something.
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        // Do something.
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        // Do something.
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        // Do something.
        break;
}
```

EDIT: To get your application to automatically rotate, you can do this:

```
- (BOOL)willAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if ((interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) NSLog(@"Right");
    if ((interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)) NSLog(@"Left");
    if ((interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)) NSLog(@"Up");
    if ((interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) NSLog(@"Down");
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Ok if I go with option one. How do I retrieve the orientation from that code and use an if/else statement depending on orientation?

Answer (score 2):

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
```

Comment: This didn't do anything for me.

Comment: It didn't get the orientation?

Comment: No how do I use it. I just added this line the NSLog orientation and got nothing. I also need it to call a specified method each time the orientation changges.

Comment: The other answer contains a switch statement that should give you an idea.