# How to check orientation in UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634745/iphone-orientation)

I want to check orientation(whether its landscape or portrait mode)  of UIView.

How can I do this ?

Comment: There's tons of posts on this as a simple search on "iPhone Check Orientation" will reveal. Please try to search first before posting.

Answer (score 8):

`UIView` Doesn't have orientation property.

You can check the current device orientation wherever you want using this:

```
    UIInterfaceOrientation  orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        //portrait
    }
    else {
        //landscape
    }
```

Comment: Its not UIInterfaceOrientation. its UIDeviceOrientation. And that will not check for landscape or portrait mode. :(

Answer (score 0):

`UIView` doesn't have orientation property. You can check `UIDevice` or `UIApplicationStatusBar` orientation

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `UIAccelerometerDelegate` (I'm assuming that you have subClassed `UIView`) in your class as `@interface YourView : UIView<UIAccelerometerDelegate>` and then in the `-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration` method, check what is the value of `acceleration.x`. If it is close to 1 or -1 then the device is held up in landscape left/right. Make the same check on `acceleration.y` to determine portrait orientation