# iOS: dimensions of search bar in navigation controller

Tags: ios

I have a UISearchBar in my navigation controller bar title view. I followed the first answer here [How to add search bar in navigation bar for iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351464/how-to-add-search-bar-in-navigation-bar-for-iphone). This works for me but the dimensions of the search bar are hardcoded. How can I set the dimensions so that it looks nice on iPad and iPhone in both portrait and landscape mode?

This is the code in my search bar controller.

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 310.0, 44)];
self.view.autoresizingMask = 0;
_searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
_searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
_searchBar.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:_searchBar];
```

Then in my main viewController I have

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = _searchController.view;
```

Comment: Show your code for adding the search bar to the nav bar.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do this, and here are some articles that may be helpful:

1. [Get the device's orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968451/different-ways-of-getting-current-interface-orientation), then use different sets of values accordingly
2. [Figure out which device the app is running on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk)
3. [Get the dimension of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677716/how-to-get-the-screen-width-and-height-in-ios)

Comment: Is there a way to do it simply programmatically? Like using autoresizing and navigation bar dimensions?