# set UIInterfaceOrientation at runtime

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.3

I have 5 view in storyboard. I want each view orientation will be different for example one view will be `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` another view will be `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` or `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` or `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown`. So how do set this orientation of view different.

I have used 
`[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];`
 but it show warning 'UIDevice may not responds to setOrientation'. According to many of the stackoverflow writers I am using

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation { 
    //return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown); 
}
```

this above code but it is not working in my project. So what is the proper procedure for the orientation of the screen.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:YES];
```

You cann't set `UIDeviceOrientation` because it's physical parameter. If you keep device in your hand in portrait - how you programmatically set it to landscape?). `UIDeviceOrientation` does mean - Device Orientation, not Interface. This answer describe differences between orientations:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3897243/194544

Comment: So is there any way to keep my device in portrait mode in programmatically?

Comment: To keep return from shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation YES for portrait orientation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` into each viewController and check for the correct orientation. If you push a viewController that only supports eg. upsideDown, it will be presented upside down.

Note:

- If you are in a tabbar environment, the behaviour is different. Please ask, if that is the case.
- If you are talking about the rootViewController your app should be setup corresponding to the first viewController (Info.plist)

Answer (score 0):

The orientation property on UIDevice is **read-only**.

You can use `[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];` to attempt to rotate all view controllers to *the devices current orientation.* You can't force set the rotation.