# Scroll bars with a translucent navigation bar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar

If you `setTranslucent` to `YES` on a `UIViewController`, it shifts the content 'up' (I suppose what it is really doing is *not* shifting it *down*).

Since all of my content is in a `UIScrollView`, the navigation bar is effectively covering the top of this scroll view. I can bump the items in the scroll view down a little, but the scroll indicators still get partially hidden under the nav bar.

I would consider moving the whole scroll bar down 44 points, except that's not going to look right in landscape orientation on an iPhone.

A vanilla UITableView seems to handle this scenario just fine - how can I do the same in my UIViewController?

EDIT

I've realized that I'm supposed to set contentInsets and scrollIndicatorInsets to 'shift' things down. But still my problem remains - In landscape mode, there is an ugly gap between the nav bar and the scroll view.

Comment: For what it's worth the documented Photos.app example doesn't exhibit the issue - the insets are seemingly different in each rotation.

Comment: That's because the navbar has a different height for each orientation.

Comment: I need to word my question a little better - yes, that's what I'm trying to get at. I can't create insets that use 'whatever the nag bar height happens to be' I don't think? The apple docs use a flat 44, which isn't going to work.

Comment: Listen for rotation notifications on your navbar and copy the height to your insets.

Comment: That's what I feared. I've heard there are many corner cases to address with that approach (e.g. device is rotated when app in background).

Comment: I notice that the question in the title as been answered, but the question now shifts to a rotation issue.

Comment: There is no question in the title. And the issue was part of the original question. As mentioned, I could have worded it better.

Comment: It was a suggestion, perhaps edit it to get more exposure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me 2 minutes to google this answer: `contentInset`

Check this question for an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10049782/2462469

After that you need to adjust `ScrollIndicatorInsets` as well.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/scrollIndicatorInsets

Edit: this fellow has similar rotation issues: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15623727/2462469
He needed to reset the scroll position after rotating back. It's an edge case though.

Comment: I just commented at the same time - I found some docs but they don't help my central issue.

Comment: Check my addition on scrollIndicatorInset

Comment: Still not helpful. I guess two minutes wasn't enough?